# Обновить таблицу используя значения из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, jdbc, update, h2, preparedstatement

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** работаю с СУБД H2. Имеются две таблицы(в проекте таблиц больше, но рассматривать будем только эти):

```
CREATE TABLE DISHES (
       id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       dish_name VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) NOT NULL,
       picture_name VARCHAR(256),
       unit VARCHAR(256),
       price DECIMAL(64,32) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(price >= 0),
       calories DECIMAL(64,32) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(calories >= 0),
       UNIQUE(dish_name)
);

CREATE TABLE DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION (
       product_id INT NOT NULL,
       dish_id INT NOT NULL,
       amount_product DECIMAL(64,32) DEFAULT 1 CHECK(amount_product > 0),
       FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
       FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES DISHES(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
       PRIMARY KEY(product_id, dish_id)
);
```

и одно представление:

```
CREATE VIEW DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
       (dish_id, price, calories) AS 
       SELECT 
       DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id, 
       SUM(PRODUCTS.price * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product),
       SUM(PRODUCTS.calories * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product)
       FROM
       DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION, PRODUCTS 
       WHERE DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id = PRODUCTS.id 
       GROUP BY DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id;
```

Необходимо обновить таблицу DISHES, а именно столбцы price и calories значениями одноименных столбцов из таблицы DISH_PRICE_CALORIES. Обновить нужно блюда включающие в себя продукт с определенным id.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** создал запрос

```
UPDATE DISHES 
       SET price = DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price, calories = DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories 
       WHERE DISHES.id = DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id AND 
       DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id AND 
       DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id = ?;
```

Сам запрос создается в виде объекта PreparedStatement.

Получаю ошибку с текстом: 
*org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Столбец "DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.DISH_ID" не найден.*

**Вопрос:** как в базе данных H2 обновить одну таблицу используя значения из другой таблицы? Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: @Akina, извините за небрежный код. Я принял ваше замечание. Что-бы вы могли сказать касательно вопроса?

Comment: *Получаю ошибку с текстом* На самом деле источник ошибки в том, что не поля, а таблицы `DISH_PRICE_CALORIES` в запросе нет (да что таблицы - секции `FROM` нет).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет что-то типа

```
UPDATE DISHES d
SET (d.price, d.calories) = ( SELECT dc.price, dc.calories 
                              FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES dc
                              WHERE d.id = dc.dish_id );
```

Правда, насчёт передаваемых параметров

> `DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id = ?`

полная неясность. Почему продукт, если обновляем блюдо?

---

> обновить нужно блюда включающие в себя продукт с определенным id

```
UPDATE DISHES d
SET (d.price, d.calories) = ( SELECT dc.price, dc.calories 
                              FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES dc
                              WHERE d.id = dc.dish_id )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION dpc
               WHERE d.id = dpc.dish_id
                 AND dpc.product_id = ? );
```

Comment: обновить нужно блюда включающие в себя продукт с определенным id.

Comment: @Bakuard Тогда надо получить список таких блюд в отдельном подзапросе и вставить его во WHERE основного запроса на обновление. Ща добавим... готово.

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста на последний вопрос: обязательно ли в вашем  sql запросе использовать псевдонимы таблиц?

Comment: @Bakuard А вот это как раз дело вкуса. Главное - чтобы в любой точке можно было однозначно определить, откуда берётся поле. Алиас таблицы способствует тому, что неоднозначностей не возникнет в принципе. Если имеются одноимённые поля, или несколько копий одной таблицы - алиасы почти что необходимы. Я, скажем, вообще считаю, что если в запросе более одной таблицы (включая копии одной таблицы, подзапросы, CTE) - алиасить надо каждое поле. Ну плюс длинные имена таблиц против коротких алиасов - это сокращение текста, он становится более обозримым.