# Обновить значения в таблице, значениями из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно обновить значение `t1` таблицы значениями из `t2`.
В обоих таблицах есть `id` и нужно только те, которые есть в обоих таблицах.

Я пробовал сделать это следующим запросом:

```
update t1 set (t1.n_dog) = (
    select t2.n_dog
    from t2
    join t1 on t1.idblank=t2.idblank);
```

на что получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Поискав на этом сайте, нашёл подобную [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043507/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B).

И там есть решение:

```
UPDATE DISHES d SET (d.price, d.calories) = ( SELECT dc.price, dc.calories 
                          FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES dc
                          WHERE d.id = dc.dish_id );
```

На мой взгляд, ситуации похожи, но только у меня один столбец.

Почему получаю эту ошибку?

Comment: У Вас в секции FROM присутствует копия обновляемой таблицы. В рабочем решении другого вопроса его нет. Неужели так сложно просто обычной заменой в текстовом редакторе заменить имена таблиц и полей в рабочем примере на свои?

Comment: А зачем удалили последний вопрос?  Уже ответ написал.

Comment: @0xdb, Хотел облегчить написал скрипт завуалированов в итоге пока написал в блокноте допустил ошибки чем ещё больше запутал)
По этому удалил

Comment: Ну ошибки то можно поправить, и если на них в комментарии указывают, то не стоит обижаться. Короткий пример лучше, чем простыня кода с десятком таблиц, и все понимают, что при соотавлении короткого примера могут быть опечатки.

Comment: Я не обижался ) Мне Акина уже дал ответ. 
А править статью и потом объяснять - я посчитал лишним

Comment: @Akalit Понимаю. Посмотрите, [как получилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1270357/217579).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
update t1 set t1.n_dog = (
    select t2.n_dog
    from t2
    where t2.idblank=t1.idblank);
```

Если сработает, то решите, что должен получить столбец `t1.n_dog`, если нет совпадения этих двух таблиц. Так, как выше, он получит значение `NULL`, если это не устраивает, см. дальше.

---

Более гибкий способ обновления из другой таблицы в следующем воспроизводимом примере. 3-и записи уже имеют желаемое значение, остаются 6-ь записей:

```
create table t1 (id, val) as
    select rownum, rownum*10 
    from dual connect by level<=9 
/
create table t2 (id, val) as
    select id, val+mod (id,3) from t1 
/
merge into t1 
using t2 on (t2.id = t1.id)
when matched then
    update set t1.val = t2.val
    where t1.val != t2.val
/

6 rows merged.
```

Comment: Не знал что в подзапросе можно обращаться к таблице указанной в запросе
Все получилось, большое спасибо !

Comment: @Akalit Рад был попмочь! Добавил ещё один пример, т.к. обновлять всю таблицу  - довольно редко встречается.