# Как получить из подсоединённой таблицы только одну последнюю запись в каждой группе?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eсть две таблицы, упрощённо:

```
create table clients (idclient int, name varchar2 (16)); 

create table comments (idclient int, text varchar2 (4000), dt date);
```

Нужно получить из таблиц три столбца: `name | dt | text`

То есть, для каждого клиента нужно получить дату и текст последнего комментария.

Использовал этот подход, но так как у клиента много комментариев, получаю более одной записи.

```
select
    clients.name, max(comments.dt), comments.text 
from clients 
left join comments on comments.idclient=clients.idclient
group by clients.name, comments.text, comments.dt
```

Как получить одну запись?

Comment: На основе удалённого вопроса одного из участников.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте с корреляционным подзапросом (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c5224dd3700ecd9d9a84cad94bc94a2)):

```
select name, dt, text
from clients 
cross apply (
    select 
        max (text) keep (dense_rank first order by dt desc) text, 
        max (dt) keep (dense_rank first order by dt desc) dt
    from comments where clients.idclient=comments.idclient) 
/

NAME    DT                  TEXT    
------- ------------------- --------
client1 2021-04-15 00:46:21 comment1
```